# Can't initialise an array

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Okay, I'm pretty new when it comes to C++ (having moved over from VB) and I can't seem to work out how to populate an array without doing:

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
```

etc etc

So as could be expected, I have tried this:

```
float posVector[3]; //Declared outside of int main() as needs to be global
posVector = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f}; //Inside int main()
```

Which is causing this error to be displayed:

```
extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
```

Nothing I have been able to locate online so far has been of any help. So any advice you can give me on fixing this will be appreciated!

Comment: What's the type of `posVector`?

Comment: God knows, it's whichever one is used in the online Zero Robotics Tournament IDE at http://zerorobotics.mit.edu

Answer (score 5):

Once the array is declared it cannot be initialized using the initializer list. You can go with

```
float posVector[] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
```

or even better go with [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> posVector = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
```

Comment: Right okay, so how do I make it globally available if it needs to be populated at run time? Can you please elaborate on std::vector?

Comment: The vector can be placed outside a function. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to create an array which will be globally available and hold the current x,y,z values for the position of a sattelite

Comment: Try to avoid global variables. When a lot of functions are involved it's hard to remember which function should write or just read from/to the array. When threading comes into the game it becomes even more horrible. Consider to `abstract` and `encapsulate` your data. You use C++, so use what it offers you.

Comment: Okay... Sounds scary, but I'll do some research and give it a shot, I know scope should be limited as far as possible.

Comment: Sorry, just tried using your vector solution, but now I'm getting this error: `‘vector’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type`

Comment: You forgot to include the vector header by using `#include <vector>`. I will add it to my answer. Good luck!

Comment: It should have done but it turns out the compiler doesn't allow any external libraries so I'll answer it myself when I get home, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
float f[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way i think: `float posVector[] { 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the question is not about INITIALIZING the array, but about assigning the array after it was already created. The answer is 'no way'. Arrays can not be assigned after they are initialized. However, arrays of fixed sizes some time might be more adequately presented as structs, and this is exactly the case! Coordinates are much better presented as structs!

Not commenting on the neccessity of global variable (most likely, not needed) here is the way to make it work:

```
struct Coordinate {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

Coordinate coord;

void foo() {
    coord = {1, 2, 3};
}
```